# SccProviderPackage package did not load correctly - VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

### Description:

Not sure what I did but one day Visual Studio Professional 2013 stopped launching.  Unlike the other similar questions asked, this is using VS2013 and the app doesn't even launch.  This dialog is all I see:

[image: Error message when launching VS2013].

Also, [here](http://pastebin.com/5267FMUx) is the log file from VS if it helps.

### What I've Tried:

- Going through Add or Remove a Program and repairing everything related to SQL (as per another question's
  answer)
- Repairing VS2013 (did not help, have done twice now)
- Clearing
  Team Foundation Server cache from
  C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache
  (and 5.0 and 6.0)
- Running devenv.exe as administrator

### What I would like to avoid:

Uninstalling and reinstalling VS2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installed update 4 because I realized I hadn't yet and everything works now.  I don't know what the underlying issue was but updating it fixed it.